# How to protect babies from mosquito bites?

Tags: toddler, infant, newborn, safety, outdoor

How do you protect kids, particularly newborns and toddlers, from mosquito bites when they are playing outside?  Especially when camping, at a park, etc.

Can someone give me some practical advice on how to protect babies from mosquito bites?

Answer (score 2):

For sleep times you can use a mosquito bed net

https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mosquito%20net%20for%20bed

To indoor day-to-day use a repellent applyed directly to the skin or a some kind of 
mosquito indoors repellent

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=mosquito+indoors+repellent&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=991&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=WAr3VJ_-IZPisATE8oCYBg&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QsAQ

To let him play in the outside be sure to combine a repellent with a sun block

If you live in an mosquito endemic area you can install plastic nets on windows, they keep most of insects in the ouside

Comment: thanks @jean: does these repellent tools are guarantee not affect my kid health?

Comment: There are many burning/evaporating types of repelants. At my own childhood my parents utilized a spiral incense device, bit awful odor but efficient. I cannot tell if all that things you plug in an outlet and evaporate chemicals are safe but I also utilized that kind of repellent for years. IMHO that dependes on the size of room and if you kids got some kind of allergie to the active ingredients but I'm not a medical doctor

Answer (score 1):

Burts bees makes a herbal insect repellent. This would be good for really little babies.

http://www.burtsbees.com/Herbal-Insect-Repellent/15299-00,default,pd.html

Also Avon makes a product called Skin So Soft that smells nice and it also repels bugs.

https://www.avon.com/category/bath-body/skin-so-soft/bug-guard?setlang=en

These products seem to be a little gentler that Off or some of the hard core bug sprays.

Comment: Hi @RachelD, I don't like to use those products

Comment: OK. The Burts bees is all natural, I'm sure there are also other natural brands. Besides that I have herd that eating bananas makes you unattractive to insects as well, but its never made a noticeable impact to me (but mosquito's love me).

Comment: @pitoukhmer - perhaps you can explain why these product recommendations are out for you? That might help other answerers. Rachel, I had forgotten about Skin-so-soft. Great reminder!

Comment: @anongoodnurse: health affecting issue, that's why I don't wanna apply to all my kids. If you have something naturally method I really appreciate

Comment: Burts bees is all natural, that's why I posted it for kids... Ingredients: glycine soja (soybean) oil, ricinus communis (castor) seed oil, rosmarinus officinalis (rosemary) leaf oil, cymbopogon schoenanthus (lemongrass) oil, thuja occidentalis (cedar) leaf oil, mentha piperita (peppermint) oilcymbopogon nardus (citronella) oil, eugenia caryophyllus (clove) flower oil, geranium maculatum (geranium) oil, tocopherol

Answer (score 1):

Mosquito netting is one option (set up a tent over them), but it restricts the child to a fairly confined area. This can work fine for a newborn who doesn't move, but a toddler who wants to run and play, not so much.

For mobile children, some sort of mosquito repellent on their body is a better choice. Typically this is a liquid spray in a can; the smell is repulsive to mosquitoes, and they won't bite.

There are a number of commercial "bug spray" products available. Many of them use diethyltoluamide (DEET) as the primary repellent. [If the potential side effects of DEET are a concern for you as a parent](http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/consultations/deet/health-effects.html), alternative products that rely on essential oils can either be purchased [or made at home](http://wellnessmama.com/2565/homemade-bug-spray/).

> Mosquitos – citronella, lemon eucalyptus, peppermint, lemon, eucalyptus, catnip, basil, clove, thyme, lemongrass, geranium, lavender *[(source, and another home recipe)](http://tasty-yummies.com/2013/07/17/homemade-essential-oil-insect-repellent-spray/)*

In both cases, the mosquitos don't like the smell and stay away from skin that's been sprayed. However, they often still bite through clothing that hasn't been sprayed, or look for untreated skin -- I once had a dozen mosquito bites in a small area of my neck that I somehow missed, with no bites anywhere else.

I personally use an herbal option (not homemade, but still just essential oils) just because we all like the smell better. However, it seems to wear off more quickly and requires application every hour or so to be most effective.